# Netty - How can I send additional request to Server and return response into Bytebuf

Tags: java, http, tcp, netty

Here is the step how the program should work:

1. Client send the request over my TCP Proxy Netty Server
2. First TCP Netty Stack always open a listening socket to listen the request from Client
3. First TCP Netty Stack send the request to second Netty Stack
4. The second Netty Stack open a connection and send the HTTP Request to Restful Spring Boot API
5. Restfull Sprint Boot API send back the HTTP Response to the second Netty Stack
6. The second Netty Stack send the response to the first Netty Stack
7. The first Netty Stack send the HttpResponse to the Client

Please check the diagram from here https://ibb.co/HTM9J6y

I have tried to read the code from here:

https://github.com/viniciusccarvalho/nano-proxy

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy

These examples show me how to build 2 Netty Stacks but they never returned the HTTP response to Client.

I tried to get a response from the second Netty Stack with below code but was not successfully.

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
      if(!(msg instanceof HttpRequest)) return;
      HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) msg;

      final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();

      // Start the second Netty Stack from here
      Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
      b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
      .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
      .handler(new ClientHttpRequestHandler(inboundChannel))
      .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
      ChannelFuture f = b.connect("www.google.com", 443);
      Channel outboundChannel = f.channel();

      // Question? How to send additional request and return response into Bytebuf here? 
      // Try to get a response from Channel or Channelfuture
      // Code below doesn't work
      ByteBuf httpResponse = f.channel().read().alloc().buffer();

      FullHttpResponse response = generateHttpResponse(httpResponse);
      writeFullHttpResponse(ctx, request, response);
}
```

Could you please help me to answer this question? How can just connect to www.google.com and return the response to Client with Netty? Thanks in advance

Comment: As written, this question is *wayyyy* to broad. You'll get the best answers on SO by asking about specific problems with your code, *and including a [mcve]* to demonstrate the issue

Comment: @MTCoster I updated the code, please check

Comment: What sort of response are you expecting? You never sent anything to google, you only connected

Comment: Yes I connected to google for example. How can I send additional request and get a response back into Bytebuff?

Comment: Did you find the answer?? @Nguyễn Hồng Quang

Comment: @TanveerAhmad I found the solution but that is quite complex and can't write down here. I can send you the whole project's code if you want.

Comment: @Nguyễn Hồng Quang, Thanks for reply. I think its better if you upload solution to githup and share the link. This will help others to solve the same problem. You can use that link as an answer to your own question as well.

Comment: @Nguyễn Hồng Quang, I am still waiting for your response. please reply